# In c++ what happens, if both objects overload operator<<? a<<b

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I thought that in

```
cout << "Hello world"
```

`cout` object has an operator overloading so we can pass `strings` into `cout` objects member function.

But in some example code I saw a class which has an operator overloading defined in it.

```
class GenericPlayer : public Hand
{
    ..
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const GenericPlayer& aGenericPlayer);
    ..
};

...
cout << aGenericPlayer << endl;
...
```

Even if it is not, what if both `cout` and `aGenericPlayer` overload `operator<<` ?

Comment: Are you asking if both `cout` and `GenericPlayer` defined an insertion operator (`<<`) for `GenericPlayer`?

Comment: If more than one definition of `operator<<` matches the given operands, then the "best" match is selected according to the complicated overload resolution rules spelled out in C++03 §13.3 `[over.match]`.  If the "best" match is not unique or does not exist, then it's an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Even if it is not, what if both cout and aGenericPlayer overload operator<< ?

`std::cout` is an `std::ostream` object, so any `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream, SomeType)` will work with `std::cout`. But the point is that the second parameter of the operator is different, so the overloads are different. The first "string" one is something like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*);
```

and the second

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const GenericPlayer& aGenericPlayer);
```

So, they are different operator overloads and there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I think you mean "so an operator<<(std::ostream&, something_else) will work with cout"?

Comment: @ReubenMorais yes, that's exactly what I meant. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

First, neither `cout` nor `aGenericPlayer` can overload
anything.  They're objects, and overloading is based on types
(even if you wouldn't normally says that type X overloads `<<`,
but rather that there is an overload of `<<` which can take a
type X as its second argument).

Second, overload resolution is based on all of the arguments,
not just one.  There are something around twenty different
overloads of `<<` for `std::istream` (which is a base class of
the type of `std::cout`), but none (at least in the standard
library) take a `GenericPlayer` as second parameter.  So they
can't be used if the second operand isn't a `GenericPlayer`.
Similarly, you could have an `operator<<( int, GenericPlayer
const& )`, in addition to the one you have; it would be called
if the left hand side had type `int`, and the right hand side
type `GenericPlayer`.  (I can't think of any case where this
wouldn't be operator overloading abuse, but the language 
certainly allows it.)

Answer (score 1):

In order for `cout` to accept a `GenericPlayer` object, you have to overload `operator<<`. `operator<<` is also called the **insertion** operator. So if you take that in context, you are inserting the output of your custom function to `cout`. The overloaded operator returns a reference to the original ostream object, which also means you can combine insertions. You must overload the insertion operator to recognize an `ostream` object on the left and a `GenericPlayer` on the right. See also [Overloading the << Operator for Your Own Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  . As far as `cout` goes, `cout` is an object of `class ostream` that represents the standard output stream. It corresponds to the `cstdio` stream `stdout`. Because `cout` is an object of class ostream, we can write characters to it either as formatted data using for example the insertion operator (ostream::operator<<) or as unformatted data using the write member function, among others

Comment: I actually agree with your basic idea, that the `<<` operator is the insertion operator.  But would this term be appropriate in a case like `BigInteger operator<<( BigInteger const& lhs, int rhs )`.  At a human reader level, too, operator `<<` is overloaded: insertion, or shift left.

Comment: @JamesKanze: When applied to an ostream operator, I believe the convention is `insertion`.

Comment: Agreed.  And for most applications, that's the _only_ use; most programmers probably think of insertion as the operator's primary meaning (although historically, it was the left shift operator first).

Comment: @JamesKanze: You might be interested in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854248/why-are-bitwise-shifts-and-used-for-cout-and-cin

Answer (score 1):

> what if both cout and aGenericPlayer overload operator<<

Neither of them overload it, it is overloaded as a regular function (not a member). Note the use of `friend` in your example; this allows the function to access the class's internals without being a member. Therefore, this situation is avoided.