# Console::WriteLine() vs. cout

Tags: c++, c++-cli, clr, cout, cin

I've just started trying to teach myself C++ (I've been a C# programmer for about a year now) and I can't understand for the life of me what the difference is between Console::WriteLine("Hello World") and cout<<"Hello World", on a side note I'm not even really sure what cout and cin even are so any help with that would also be appreciated

Comment: `Console::WriteLine` isn't C++. It's C++/CLI, which is more or less C++ running on .NET.

Comment: By the way, `cout` is an `ostream` object for `stdout`. `cin` is an `istream` object for `stdin`.

Answer (score 9):

You are using C++/CLI and not just C++.
C++/CLI is a Microsoft extension which allows you to write .NET code on Windows and allows you to use the .NET Library(CLR - Common Language Runtime).

Console::WriteLine is a method from the .NET Library - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxcchfk6.aspx

When you are create a Project in Visual C++, it allows you to either create a C++ Project or a C++/CLI (CLR) project. The CLR Projects types are the ones where you can use .NET stuff. If you create a Win32 project or one of the other types, it's just C++.

If you are not creating projects & just compiling from the command line, then the `/clr` option is the one to use for C++/CLI.

`cout` & `cin` are `iostream` objects. The corresponding classes have operators `<<` & `>>` overloaded - hence you are able to do output with `cout<<` & input with `cin>>`.

This [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854248/why-are-bitwise-shifts-and-used-for-cout-and-cin) gives a better understanding of why the design used `<<` & `>>`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers but what really confuses me is that Console::WriteLine and cout<< seem to DO the same thing and I found it very unlikely that all Console::WriteLine does is call cout<< otherwise they wouldn't have even bothered making it so can someone also help me with that? Thanks

Comment: @EhrenPatel `Console::WriteLine` is part of the .NET library. The .NET Library is available for use from C#, VB# etc. Those languages do not have `cout`.

Comment: Does C++ have any standard function that writes a line to the console, i.e. automatically puts an `endl` at the end of your input?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - `puts`

Comment: @user93353 Thank you, I didn't know about that. But is there one that works for more than just strings?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - no

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that `std::cout` is standard and is therefore available in any C++ compiler on any platform, whereas `Console` is a Microsoft-specific extension.