# What is the function execution order in code like foo(bar())?

Tags: c++, c

Assume we have code like this in C or C++:

```
foo(bar());
```

What is the function execution order in this case?

1. Is it required that `bar()` is called first, and `foo()` is called no earlier than `bar()` returns, in which case `foo()` is passed the return value of `bar()`?
2. Is it permitted that the compiler reorders the above, namely that it calls `foo()` first, and delays calling `bar()` until in the code of `foo()` the value of `foo()`’s parameter is actually needed?

Case 2 could be useful for optimization should `foo()` be defined like this:

```
void foo(someType par) {
    if(someTest())
        baz1();
    else
        baz2(par);
}
```

In which case calling `bar()` could even be completely skipped if `someTest()` returns `false`.

However, case 2 would also make the programmer have to be more careful, as it could sometimes lead to subtle bugs (for example with recurrence).

Comment: bar() is called first.

Comment: As long the _observable behaviour_ is the same, there might be no function call at all. And pick **one** language! C and C++ are different languages with very different semantics!

Comment: Similar but more intricate for C++17: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is it required that `bar()` is called first […]?

The code is required to behave as if that's what's happening.

> 2. Is it permitted that the compiler reorders the above […]?

Yes, if the observable behavior is the same as if `bar()` was evaluated first.

This is known as the [**"as-if" rule**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15718262/3425536):

> […] an implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this International Standard as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed, as far as can be determined from the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: Are you sure?  [expr.call] states *The evaluations of the postfix expression and of the arguments are all unsequenced relative to one another. All side effects of argument evaluations are sequenced before the function is entered*

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, the standard quotes in the linked Q&A seem to support this.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, [intro.execution]:

> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function.

`bar()` must be evaluated before the call to `foo` begins.

There was some change in C++17 that the expression `a(b)` now evaluates `a` before `b` whereas before they were unsequenced. In this case, the evaluation of `foo` doesn't do anything, it's just an identifier. But had we had `foo()(bar())`, then the call to `foo()` would be sequenced before the call to `bar()`, whereas prior to C++17, the two were unsequenced.

Comment: That would complete forbid inlining and full-code optimisation. If that is about C++, it is very different for C.

Comment: @Olaf No it doesn't, it simply explains what the observable behavior is. The observable behavior is that `bar()` is evaluated first.

Comment: "is sequenced **before execution** of every expression or statement in the body of the called function." - that goes much further than observable behaviour. OB allows to reorder statements arbitrarily, as long the OB does not change. This line explicitly forbids it. It might be because of C++ having constructors/destructors, etc. But it is definitively way more restrictive than in C (the question is unfortunately tagged both).

Comment: @Olaf: But 1.9 [intro.execution] says "[conforming implemenations] need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below." That applies also to "sequenced before"; only observable behaviour is required to happen in order.

Comment: @rici: If you refer to the C++ standard: I'm not really into it (I'm a C person). If that is so, it should be part of the answer as it relaxes requirements indeed. I just wanted to point out from the text shown, it would be more strict than in C.

Comment: The citation is not related to when `a` and `b` are evaluated relative to each other. `a` is not the body of the function, but the expression yielding a function. The body is the code at the function definition.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm fully aware of your Cness :) and indeed it is from the C++ standard (I should have written 1.9.1, though). But it's essentially the same definition of "sequenced before" as provided by the C standard (although the sequenced-before *rules* are different); in both cases, it only applies to observed behaviour. (It's also possible that C++ and C can observe different behaviours, but the clauses look very similar to me.)

Comment: @Olaf: `a` **is** the "postfix expression designating the called function"

Comment: @riciYes, I got that from your comment, but it cannot be concluded from the answer, which makes my comment relevant. Not sure, but doesn't C++17 (at least) support defered evaluation? That would raise the question to another level of too broad, I suspect.

Comment: "... postfix expression designating ..." - Whatever, I did not recall the exact term. Point is it is definitively not the function body the answer refers to.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said, you might consider

```
  foo( bar1(), bar2() );
```

which is a more interesting case. Here, the order is allowed to be [bar1, bar2, foo] or [bar2, bar1, foo].

Answer (score 0):

There is a sequence point after function argument evaluation (i.e. before the code of any function is entered). Hence, `bar()` must be evaluated before `foo(...)` will be entered. Confer, for example, the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> 6.5.2.2 Function calls: (10) There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call. Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.

Comment: Please use the _valid_ standard, not an outdated version for reference. And this does not specify how the generated machine code works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following statement

```
foo(bar());
```

The function `bar()` will be called before `foo()`. The compiler cannot reorder these function calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's same as :

```
type bar_result = bar();
foo(bar_result);
```

1. bar() will be called first.
2. bar_result is passed as a copy/referencie.

Comment: The result of `bar()` is not necessarily passed as a copy, for example if `foo` takes its parameter as a reference.

Comment: granted, would you please put an example?

Comment: `void foo(const type&) { }`

Comment: You are right. I would improve the answer. Thank you.