# int i=0; foo(++i, ++i, ++i); well defined?

Tags: c++, c++17

If I understand the C++17 standard correctly then function arguments should be indeterminately sequenced (P0145R3).
Please consider the following testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int a, int b, int c) { printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c); }
int main() {
  int i = 0;
  foo(++i, ++i, ++i);
}
```

clang warns incorrectly:

> warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]

and prints: 1 2 3

gcc also warns:

> warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

and prints: 3 3 3

Which output is correct?

Comment: Undefined behavior. Thus, anything goes and they are both "correct"

Comment: Isn't the implementation vendor specific as the standard states that argument evaluation order is unspecified? So both are valid according to the standard

Comment: If they're indeterminately sequenced wouldn't either be "correct"? That's kind of what undefined behavior means. Everything in your question states the same.

Comment: (And what makes the clang warning incorrect? It's telling you exactly what you stated is the behavior.)

Comment: Well, P0145 says that function call arguments are indeterminately sequenced. So any permutation of "1 2 3" seems valid.

Comment: @DaveNewton "Indeterminately sequenced" != "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The linked question doesn't address the changes in C++17 at all, so I wouldn't consider it a duplicate.

Comment: @sepp2k Then how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17? Which basically says that the argument evaluation order is still unspecified.

Comment: @sepp2k In general, no, but in this case, I'd argue it does, since you cannot rely on evaluation order. Since you can't rely on the order, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @DaveNewton The difference between unspecified and undefined, is that undefined may cause the program to go complete bananas, crash & burn, launch random computer games etc. Whereas unspecified means that the program behaves deterministically but you can't assume anything about the order.

Comment: @Lundin Fair enough-I should use the terms properly. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization of the function parameters is unsequenced as per a note in  C++17 5.2.2/4:

> When a function is called, each parameter (8.3.5) shall be initialized (8.5, 12.8, 12.1) with its corresponding
>   argument. [ Note: Such initializations are indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other (1.9) —
>   end note ]

Meaning that even if the function arguments are guaranteed to be evaluated left-to-right (which I can't find any info about in C++17 draft), the initialization of the arguments is still indeterminately sequenced.

Meaning that for example, if your parameters all call the same copy constructor, which in turn modifies a global/static resource, your program has unspecified behavior:

```
static int f;

Foo::Foo (const Foo& foo)
  : x(f++)
{}

...

void func (Foo a, Foo b, Foo c)
{
  std::cout << a.x << b.x << c.x;  // unspecified output
}
```

A good compiler will give a warning upon spotting reliance on unspecified behavior = deterministic but undocumented behavior, which you can't assume anything about.

Comment: Then both warnings are bogus and clang's output is right (any other permutation of 1,2,3 would also be correct).

Comment: Your answer says "unsequenced", but your quote says "indeterminately sequenced". Those are very different: indeterminately sequenced is still sequenced and so free of undefined behavior (it's just unspecified as you then correctly say)