# Is printf("%d %d", i++, i++) defined behaviour in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

I seen quora question https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-features-introduced-in-C++17 about **C++17 best features**, where I read `printf("%d %d", i++, i++)` 
**no longer undefined behavior in C++17**.

Last to second paragraph of [answer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-features-introduced-in-C++17) written by **Sergey Zubkov**:

> Oh, and **it’s no longer undefined behavior to do printf("%d %d", i++,
>   i++)**, although it’s still undefined behavior to do i++ + i++.

So, I have a question in my mind, **is it really defined behaviour in C++17**?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17: looks like it's now *unspecified* rather than *undefined*

Comment: It's still a bad idea to write this code whether or not it is undefined!