# c++17 evaluation order with operator overloading functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards, c++17

Regarding this question

[What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17)

With this specification

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf

And this text from the specification

> Furthermore, we suggest the following additional rule: **the order of
>   evaluation of an expression involving an overloaded operator is
>   determined by the order associated with the corresponding built-in
>   operator, not the rules for function calls.**

Does this mean that these two expressions are no longer equivalent?

```
a << b;
operator<<(a, b);
```

As the second one looks like a function call, hence there is no guaranteed evaluation order in the parameters?

Comment: That's correct, the two different syntaxes have different semantics now. The operator syntax has its peculiar semantics, the function call syntax has the (new!) semantics of function calls.

Comment: @KerrekSB This is precisely why this proposal: 
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0431r0.htm 
was written but I don't believe it gained any traction.

Comment: @ForeverLearning: It is certainly a subject that inspires hearts, minds and proposals!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *"As the second one looks like a function call, hence there is no guaranteed evaluation order in the parameters?"*

Indeed. [[expr.call]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.call) contains an example specifically covering the difference between the two cases covered in your question [**emphasis mine**]:

> The postfix-expression is sequenced before each expression in the
>   expression-list and any default argument. The initialization of a
>   parameter, including every associated value computation and side
>   effect, **is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other
>   parameter**.
>
> ...
>
> Note: If an operator function is invoked using operator notation,
>   **argument evaluation is sequenced as specified for the built-in
>   operator**; see
>   [[over.match.oper]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.oper).
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   S(int);
> };
> int operator<<(S, int);
> int i, j;
> int x = S(i=1) << (i=2);
> int y = operator<<(S(j=1), j=2);
> ```
>
> After performing the initializations, the value of `i` is `2` (see
>   [[expr.shift]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.shift)), but **it is unspecified** whether the value of `j` is
>   `1` or `2`.
>
> — end example ]

Comment: Look no further than: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0431r0.htm
Proposal was DOA though.

Comment: @ForeverLearning thanks for the related link, that's interesting.