# Is (++x > ++x) well-defined in c++?

Tags: c++, side-effects, sequence-points

I read a bit about undefined behavior regarding side-effects and sequence points and their replacement in C++11. ([Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points))

It raised the following question. Does this code have defined behavior?

```
int x = 0;
bool result = ++x > ++x;
```

Does it matter which C++ standard is used?

Comment: The REAL answer is: write code where you don't need to worry about stuff like this

Comment: Think about it this way:  does `bool result = operator>(++x, ++x);` have well-defined behaviour?  The asnwer is a resounding no.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy This notation for operators takes away their sequencing properties, so you can't really use this reasoning. Also this notation doesn't work for built-in operators.

Comment: Looks undefined to me, check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order to be sure.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Are you saying that there is a difference regarding sequencing between inline and function notation calls of an operator? That would be surprising to me. (There *may* be a difference regarding sequencing of the subexpression within a larger surrounding expression -- e.g. `op(x++) + x++` is sequenced and defined.)

Comment: [C++17 evaluation order with operator overloading functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408002/c17-evaluation-order-with-operator-overloading-functions) and [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17) should be useful to you.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yep, starting with C++17. Pre-C++17 operators lose their sequencing properties merely when overloaded, regardless of used notation. See (16) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) (ctrl+f "lose their special sequencing properties")

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well, those operators that sequence the evaluation of their arguments in the first place (i.e. && and ||)). Not directly relevant here.