# Side-effect of function call sequence order

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int f() {
    std::cout << 0;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << f();
}
```

It [outputs](https://godbolt.org/z/nnsx7GjE3) the following text:

```
01
```

Is this guaranteed by the standard though? The following things happen (not neccesarly in order)

- (A) side effects of `std::cout` (not observable here)
- (B) value evaluation of `std::cout`
- (C) side effects of `f()` (print `0`)
- (D) value evaluation of `f()`
- (E) side effects of the `<<` operator (print `1`)
- (F) value evaluation of the `<<` operator

Reading the order of evaluation rules on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) I managed to find the following:

- Rule 2) says that (B) and (D) happen before (F).
- Rule 19) (C++17) says that (A) and (B) happen before (C) and (D)

I could imagine, that there is a rule that says the side effects of a function happen before the return of a value, that means (C) happens before (D). I am not a hundred percent sure about where this is explicitely written down though. Maybe rule 11)?

That leaves (E) which I could not find a sequence rule for. Rule 2) explicitely excludes side effects from the sequence order, so:

- What are the rules for (E)?
- Is this guaranteed to be sequenced after the other observable side effect (C)?

Note:
I stumbled on this problem when discussing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72458369/17862371) recent question, which is related but more about sequencing of chained `<<` operators. I wanted to ask for this specific question in a more condensed form and with more of my own reasoning behind it.

Comment: I asked a similar question 4 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51784836/3684343 Yes, it is guaranteed by the standard, first `cout` will be evaluated, then `f()` will be evaluated (prints 0) and then `cout << 1` will be evaluated.

Comment: f() is a subexpression used as an argument in a function call to operator<<(cout, f()), so the rules you're looking for are the ones about function calls.  "3)" in the cppreference page.

Comment: @Cubbi no, the rule for `<<` apply here (left before right), not the rule for function arguments (unspecified which one first): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408392/3684343

Comment: @mch my comment was not about argument vs argument (which indeed became l-to-r for overloaded shifts in C++17, but also doesn't make a difference in this example), but about arguments vs body