# Passing variable to multiple functions in the same statement, is this a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I ran into strange behavior in VC++2010, and I think it's a compiler bug, unless I'm missing something obvious:

```
class A
{
public:
    A& B(int& value)
    {
        value = 10;
        return *this;
    }
    A& C(int value)
    {
        printf("%d\r\n", value);
        return *this;
    }
    A& D(int value1, int value2)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\r\n", value1, value2);
        return *this;
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    int x = 0; // get uninitialized variable warning if I don't assign x
    a.B(x).C(x).D(x, x - 1);
}
```

I would expect:

```
10
10, 9
```

But it actually prints:

```
10
10, -1
```

It's obviously assuming x can't be modified by any of the prior function calls and replaces "x - 1" with "-1".

Is this somehow invoking undefined behavior, and thus acting unexpectedly, or is it a compiler bug?

Comment: Yes. The evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified. The longer the expression, the more chances of reordering.

Comment: So it can evaluate all the variables for all the functions in any order before it calls any of them?

Comment: @StoryTeller the order of function arguments across the entire expression or within one function call?

Comment: @RichardHodges - *"within one function call"* depends on the standard revision you are quoting. Across the entire expression is the same as it always was IIRC.

Comment: @BryceWagner - Not *all* of them. Since the result of some functions are needed to call others. But that `x - 1` can be evaluated at any point the compiler so chooses.

Comment: @StoryTeller Really? When did that change. Because C++17 still has unspecified ordering of arguments inside a function call (it did change from UB if that is what you are referring too).

Comment: @StoryTeller you're right. they fixed it in c++17 to allow future continuations to work.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - The change they made is best [described by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46472497/817643). Not highly relevant here, but regardless.

Comment: I suppose this behavior makes some sort of sense if you think of it in nested form, so it's actually calling D(C(B(a, x), x), x, x - 1).

Comment: in g++ 6.3 and VC2017 the result is `0\n 0, -1`, which is perfectly logic, given the parsing starts from the extreme right going left. in assembly it pushes the address of `this` pointer and `x` which at the first time is `0`, the evaluation of `D` is passed to the function call `C` then to `B`, at the time of calling `D(x, x-1)` `x` is perfectly known and doesn't depend on any other variable. So I think it is a bug in VC10