# How stack frames look like when two functions lie in one line?

Tags: c++

For example, we have

```
int p(void) {
  return 4;
}

int q(void) {
  return 5;
}

int main(void) {
  int x = p() + q();
  return 0;
}
```

How does the stack frame look like in this case? To be exact, are p and q evaluated simultaneously, or after p is first evaluated to be 4, the program proceeds to q?

Comment: 1. In single threaded environment only one function can be executed at a time. 2. Formatting your code does not change compilation result.

Comment: Compile it to assembly if you're curious about stack frame or such low-level things.

Comment: Any order is allowed in most C++ operators (except, for example, `||` and `&&` which are short circuiting). But in this case any modern compiler with optimizations turned on will just remove everything you wrote, because it has no side effects.

Comment: It depends on the compiler, the compiler flags and other factors. To find out check it yourself with your favorite debugger.

Answer (score 4):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators
> (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a
> function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the
> subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified. The compiler can
> evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the
> same expression is evaluated again.
>
> There are exceptions to this rule which are noted below.
>
> Except where noted below, there is no concept of left-to-right or
> right-to-left evaluation in C++. This is not to be confused with
> left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the
> expression f1() + f2() + f3() is parsed as (f1() + f2()) + f3() due to
> left-to-right associativity of operator+, **but the function call to f3
> may be evaluated first, last, or between f1() or f2() at run time**

Comment: Note that after C++17 things have been tighted up a tad.  For example, `f(a()+x(),b(),c)` -- in C++17 you cannot evaluate `b()` between `a()` and `x()` and `+`.  I do not recall if similar restrictions where applied to `+`; if it was, then the order of `f1()+f2()` vs `f3()` was unspecified, but you would no longer be able to evaluate `f3()` between `f1()` and `f2()`.  I do not have the new rules memorized, but you should be aware that they have changed, so cppreference may be out of date.

Comment: @Yakk could you please point me to the specific section which talks about these changes. i was lookin at C++ 17 specification and i could only find this from section 8.2 "The
initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately
sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17 -- that SO post contains more than I know.