# std::make_shared() change in C++17

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, make-shared, exception-safety

In [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), the following holds until C++17:

> code such as `f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g())` can cause a
>   memory leak if `g` gets called after `new int(42)` and throws an
>   exception, while `f(std::make_shared<int>(42), g())` is safe, since
>   two function calls are never interleaved.

I'm wondering which change introduced in C++17 renders this no longer applicable.

Comment: The answer on the similar question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17

Comment: So... we don't need `make_shared` anymore? (though it's still handy)

Comment: @Mehrdad There are other benefits. Trade-offs are discussed on the cppref page I linked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The evaluation order of function arguments are changed by [P0400R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0400r0.html).

Before the change, evaluation of function arguments are unsequenced relative to one another. This means evaluation of `g()` may be inserted into the evaluation of `std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42))`, which causes the situation described in your quoted context.

After the change, evaluation of function arguments are indeterminately sequenced with no interleaving, which means all side effects of `std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42))` take place either before or after those of `g()`. Now consider the case where `g()` may throw.

- If all side effects of `std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42))` take place before those of `g()`, the memory allocated will be deallocated by the destructor of `std::shared_ptr<int>`.
- If all side effects of `std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42))` take place after those of `g()`, there is even no memory allocation.

In either case, there is no memory leak again anyway.

Answer (score 20):

The [P0145R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) paper (which [was accepted](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0636r2.html#new-core-global) into C++17) refines the order of evaluation of several C++ constructs, including

> Postfix expressions are evaluated from left to right. This includes functions calls and member
>   selection expressions

Specifically, the paper adds the following text to 5.2.2/4 paragraph of the standard:

> The postfix-expression is sequenced before each expression in the
>   expression-list and any default argument. Every value computation and
>   side effect associated with the initialization of a parameter, and the
>   initialization itself, is sequenced before every value computation and
>   side effect associated with the initialization of any subsequent
>   parameter.

Comment: Wow, having not followed C++17 at all, this is an almost-mindblowingly substantial change! Of course if we all did our jobs properly it ought to be entirely transparent to us but, still... wow.

Comment: Hang on, the open-std.org page summary doesn't match the paper's text you quoted. One says that the order is now indeterminate (not unspecified) - it means the evaluations can't be interleaved (which I thought was already the case in C++11). The paper itself does use the term "subsequent" which suggests the order is quite determinate. Which is it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep, this makes me puzzled too. The paper itself mentions left-to-right as an informal suggestion, but the other link says it's indeterminate. I'm not quite sure how to parse the patch to 5.2.2/4, though.

Comment: Okay I think it's the nesting behaviour that's improved. So we are guaranteed that, when `g()` happens, _if_ the `new` happened already then the `shared_ptr` construction has too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501596/560648 However the order between the `shared_ptr` construction and `g()` is still not known.

Comment: @lisyarus: I doubt the order of evaluation of the arguments would change simply because gcc/clang use right-to-left while MSVC use left-to-right and I doubt either would be keen in changing this; it is likely that software out there relies on their current behavior.

Comment: This is so subtle and intricate. I don't think it's good practice to write code that relies on this.

Comment: I think xskxzr answers my question more directly and clearly in human language as opposed to arcane standard text, so I will accept his answer instead. Still, your answer along with the discussion in the comment section are very useful, which well deserve an up-vote :)