# Increment int in an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int c = counts.at(v).at(id);
std::cout << c;
counts.at(v).emplace(id,c+1);
std::cout << counts.at(v).at(id);
```

counts is an unordered_map of unordered_map. The first cout prints 1, the second prints 1, why it is not incremented ?

Comment: Check what emplace guarantees if the element already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`emplace` does not insert anything if that key already exists, so instead you could use the following

```
counts.at(v)[id] += 1;
```

The `operator[]` will either default construct a value if that key does not exist, or will return a modify-able reference if it does exist

Comment: It will [value initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the object, which in the case of `int`, is different from default construction. (initializing it to zero vs leaving it uninitialized)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Perhaps my sentence construction was confusing, but that is precisely what I meant, that the int will be initialized to zero. The first sentence mentioned value initialization first, and default construction second. The clarification analogously mentioned initialization to zero first, followed by non-initialization.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yep okay I'm with you now.

Answer (score 1):

You've already found how to get to the element in question:

```
counts.at(v).at(id);
```

Per [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at), this is a reference (until you copy it into a new object, like `c`), so you can simply increment it:

```
counts.at(v).at(id)++;
```

Or, if we're assuming both keys already exist (or you don't mind them being created if they don't), as they do in your code:

```
counts[v][id]++;
```

… which, in my opinion, is much easier to read.

The `emplace` function is for creating a new element where none previously existed.

---

In totality, then:

```
std::cout << counts[v][id] << ' ';
counts[v][id]++;
std::cout << counts[v][id];
```

Or, if you don't want the repeated lookups:

```
auto& elm = counts[v][id];
std::cout << elm << ' ';
elm++;
std::cout << elm;
```

You could even shorten it further (though this is less clear):

```
auto& elm = counts[v][id];
std::cout << elm++ << ' ';
std::cout << elm;
```

Or, [since C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501596/560648):

```
auto& elm = counts[v][id];
std::cout << elm++ << ' ' << elm;
```