# Why function argument evaluation cannot be ordered?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, standards, evaluation

As far as we know, the function argument evaluation order is not defined by c++ standard.
For example:

```
 f(g(), h());
```

So we know it is undefined.
My question is, why cant c++ standard define the order of evaluation from left to right??

Comment: Optimization. Compiler might choose the best order to evaluate expressions, if it sees possibility for optimization. And besides, why would you need left-to-right order?

Comment: i mean for example left to right, it could be any order

Comment: Not a duplicated, I am familiar with that question @codekaizer, but it does not answer my question overall, it just says that better code can be generated.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan so does this not answer your question: "Better code can be generated in the absence of restrictions on expression evaluation order"

Comment: Related: [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17)

Comment: For example, when pushing parameters on the stack, functions with a variable number of arguments (`printf`) might work the best if you evaluate right-to-left so the first argument always ends up on top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no good reason to do so.

The c++ standard generally only defines what is necessary and leaves the rest up to implementers.

This is why it produces fast code and can be compiled for many platforms.

Comment: Note that C++17 changes this slightly: [C++17 evaluation order guarantees (P0145R3)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) .

Comment: @JesperJuhl didn't know things had changed. As far as I can tell from reading that link though is that the order of parameter evaluation within a single function call is still undefined?

Comment: I did say "changes it *slightly*" ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I wasn't criticising your comment, it was a good one and I learnt something, was just checking I'd understood the standardese

Comment: I didn't take it as criticism :-)