# Does an overloaded bitwise-or operator ('|') have a well-defined evaluation-order?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, bitwise-or

If my C++ class has overloaded the bitwise-OR operator (`|`), does the C++ language spec guarantee that the arguments passed to a series of calls to that operator will be evaluated left-to-right?  Or is the order-of-evaluation implementation-defined (or undefined)?

(IIRC C++'s built-in `|` operator has implementation-defined order-of-evaluation; but perhaps it is different when the operator has been overloaded for a class?)

Below is a program that exemplifies what I'm asking:  Is this program guaranteed to print out `0 1 2 3 4` (as it does on the Mac I'm currently sitting at), or might it legally print out `4 3 2 1 0` (or some other ordering) in certain environments?

```
#include <iostream>

class mytype_t
{
public:
   mytype_t(int v) : _val(v) {/* empty */}

   mytype_t operator | (const mytype_t & rhs) const {return (_val | rhs._val);}

private:
   int _val;
};

mytype_t func(int v)
{
   std::cout << v << std::endl;
   return mytype_t(v);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
   mytype_t x = func(0) | func(1) | func(2) | func(3) | func(4);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to specify what vintage C++ standard you are targeting, since there are big changes in the last one.

Comment: Also see [What are the evaluation order guarantees introduced by C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38501587/1708801)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the built in operator prescribes a specific sequencing, the arguments are evaluated in the same order for the overload as well. Here is the relevant paragraph (from n4659, the C++17 draft), emphasis mine:

> **[over.match.oper]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.oper#2) If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration,
>   a user-defined operator function might be declared that implements
>   this operator or a user-defined conversion can be necessary to convert
>   the operand to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator. In
>   this case, overload resolution is used to determine which operator
>   function or built-in operator is to be invoked to implement the
>   operator. Therefore, the operator notation is first transformed to the
>   equivalent function-call notation as summarized in Table 12 (where @
>   denotes one of the operators covered in the specified subclause).
>   **However, the operands are sequenced in the order prescribed for the
>   built-in operator** (Clause [expr]).

So no, the overloaded `operator|` will not have a well-defined evaluation order, because the built-in doesn't have one.

Comment: Does it hold since C++17? There is no such sentence in the C++11 Standard.

Comment: @DanielLangr - Yes. I assumed latest as is customary unless tagged otherwise. Made it explicit.