# Can | be used as a pipe in C++

Tags: c++

This video suggests that the | is used to pass data through the functions

Is this something, the bitwise or can do, or did I miss something?

```cpp
auto selection = data | drop(from)
                      | take(to - from)
                      | filter(predicate);
```

(See the second example:
https://youtube.com/shorts/weGxJilk-c4)

Comment: This is a specific overload of the binary `|` operator for the C++20 [`ranges`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) library.

Comment: bitwise or `|` is a normal operator that you can overload to your likings like most other operators, so yes you can use it as a pipe. C++20 already does this, you can google _C++20 ranges_.

Comment: Well, operators can be overloaded, so yes.

Comment: `|` names an operator, `operator|`. It can be used for bitwise OR for numeric/binary and similar types, or it can be freely overloaded to represent any functionality that's compatible with the structure of a binary operator.

Comment: Note that the order of evalations of the `|` operator is implementation-defined, so you may find that your `drop()`, `take()`, and `filter()` functions are not being called in the order you expected them to be called in, on some platforms!

Comment: Here's the thing, it's not bitwise or. It's the same token, but the semantics are completely different. Kinda like `>>` is right shift in core C++, but is "extraction" in the stream library. In this case, calling it a "pipe" would be more appropriate indeed.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner • when did the associativity of [`operator|`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) change from being left-to-right to being implementation-defined?

Comment: @Eljay not the associativity; the order-of-operations.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513909/does-an-overloaded-bitwise-or-operator-have-a-well-defined-evaluation-orde

Comment: @JeremyFriesner • that makes sense, thank you.  Piping shouldn't rely on sequencing, but I see how someone could have (inadvertently) put in some sequencing dependent code if they weren't careful.  Sometimes C++ is a sharp knife.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this something, the bitwise or can do?

Yes.  The bitwise or `|` acts like a *bitwise or* when used on integer types.

On other types, such as classes, this operator can be **overloaded** to have whatever behavior the class author wishes.  In your code, it is operating on classes from the [ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) in the standard library, and you are right that it works similarly to a "pipe".

You have seen something very similar done with the *bitshift operator* `<<` when used on classes derived from `std::basic_ostream` such as

```
std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
```