# C++ sequence points and changes to evaluation order in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

I am a bit confused about the way the [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17) to C++17 affect the rule that you should not modify one variable 2 times between sequence points.

For example is this specified, unspecified or undefined in C++17?

```
void func(int x, int y);
int x=47;
func(x++,x++);
```

My guess would be UB.

edit: extra datapoint: clang HEAD in c++2a mode gives

[prog.cc:8:11: warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'x' [-Wunsequenced]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AC95Dlwyq9RVg6WI)

edit2: same with gcc HEAD in C++2a mode

prog.cc:8:15: warning: operation on 'x' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

edit3: with preincrement gcc and clang give [different results](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BBST1iOtdfktjUe8)

Comment: Well, the answer you linked says `f(i++, i)
was undefined but is now unspecified.`

Comment: According to your link, the order of the evaluation of the parameters is unspecified, it does not cause UB, when depending on the order.

Comment: In other words, if it helps: There are now sequence points (in unspecified order) between evaluations of each function parameter.

Comment: We don't have sequence points [since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm not saying we have, it's just might be easier to understand for some if said that way.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "*I am a bit confused about the way the changes to C++17 affect the rule that you should not modify one variable 2 times between sequence points.*" It doesn't. Even if that had become well-defined behavior, you *shouldn't* deliberately write code like that. These rules are primarily intended for cases where you have no choice, like parameter pack fold expressions, places where variable changes are not easily visible, and the like. You shouldn't use them as an excuse for more `++` abuse.

Comment: @NicolBolas language lawyer questions get asked all the time... Also if somebody is reading this in future: IMAO this is NOT a duplicate Q.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: First, you didn't use the proper tag for that. Second, you cited a rule that is not just a rule of the language; it is a rule of good coding practices. If you had cited the standard specifically, where it says these things are undefined, that would be a different matter.

Comment: I disagree, but anyway it does not matter now since Q is IMAO wrongly closed, so this is just spam for future readers. So if somebody in the future is reading this: my guess is still that code is UB, but I am not sure.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "*my guess is still that code is UB, but I am not sure.*" Even ignoring the fact that you can work out your answer entirely from information on the duplicate, you got three answers here, *all of which* say that it not UB (though one of them is flatly wrong as to *why*). So how you came to such a guess is beyond me.

Comment: @NicolBolas well long story short is that I have no reason to explain to you why I do not consider 3 bad answers or unrelated question authoritative.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: I have embellished the main answer on the duplicate in a way that more directly addresses your question. But if you find that deficient in some way, you'll have to explain how if you want an answer ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas tnx, but now you are telling me that 2 different compilers give wrong warning? (I know warnings are not required to be 100% correct, but still seems weird)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: It seems like what you're *really* asking is "if the standard says that this is unspecified, why do GCC and Clang say that they're undefined?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191570/discussion-between-nosenseetal-and-nicol-bolas).

Answer (score 2):

The example in your question

```
int x = 0;
f(x++, x++);
```

Is now unspecified behavior, rather than undefined behavior. That means that it’s valid code, but what actually happens may differ between compilers.

Comment: The phrase "unspecified behavior" is essentially meaningless.  It would be better to say that an implementation may choose in *unspecified fashion* from among the behaviors that could result from evaluating the arguments, individually, in some arbitrary order.

Comment: You should propose changing the wording! The standards committee is really open to community input, and they encourage everyone to write up and submit papers. It’s a very democratic process

Comment: I don't think the Standard ever describes any *particular* action as invoking "unspecified behavior".  Rather, it describes various particular choices an implementation may make in unspecified fashion.  The only places the Standard uses the phrase "unspecified behavior" are when referring collectively to actions whose behavior isn't fully specified [e.g. saying that a program can be correct without all aspects of its behavior being fully specified].

Comment: BTW, I think a bigger "wording" problem is the lack of a term to describe actions which should behave in predictable or at least bounded fashion in cases where that would be useful and practical (based on an implementation's target platform and the purposes for which it claims to be suitable), but need not do so in cases that would be useless or impractical.  Unfortunately, I don't see any realistic prospect of consensus on such a thing, since some compiler writers are too heavily invested in the notion that all forms of UB should be allowed to "jump the rails".

Comment: Does "unspecified behavior" require "consistent behavior"? Is the compiler required to create identical output every time? Or could it choose a different behavior on Tuesdays and still be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the evaluation of the parameters is unspecified, it means that the compiler can evaluate the parameter in any order, but should not invoke UB. This is nessecary for parameters with an allocation for example, allocation has itself a sideeffect, but for the semantic of the program, the order of allocation should not matter.

```
class person;

// consumes 2 persons, needs to delete them later
void use_persons(person* a, person* b);

int main() {
    // Alice can be allocated before or after Bob
    use_persons(new person("Alice"), new person("Bob"));
}
```