# Member call over operator<<

Tags: c++

Here is my problem:

```
int addsomeStuff(std::ostream &cout, int b) {
    cout << b;
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    cout << a << addsomeStuff(cout, 3) << endl;
    return 0;
}

Output: 312
```

Can Someone explain me the Output, i would expect the output more like 132
why is the compiler runs first the Function before making the operator.

**How i run into this issue:**
I have a container class which can hold data inside an bytearray.
Somehow the 'container.WriteConvert(..);' get inserted into bytearray before the integer called 'a'. Does anyone have an explaintation for that.

I could make the WriteConvert static or add an extra Line **which would fix this problem**, instead of returning an Container& but i am kinda intrested whats the reason the Compiler puts this in this order.

```
    int a = 2;
    Container container;
    container << a << container.WriteConvert("TestString");

    int b = 0;
    container >> b;
    cout << b;

    // The ouput of 'b' is some stupid Data which is caused by WriteConvert.
```

The Reason i didnt wrote this WriteConvert static or outside of the Container class has some reason. I have also ReadConvert which i dont want to have multiline. If someone has another idea i am open for other solutions, without increasing line amount.

```
    int b = 0;
    string output
    container >> b >> container.ReadConvert(output);
    cout << b;
```

Comment: Update your compiler and/or configure it to use the latest language standard. Since C++17 it has to print 132.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre `C++17`, the order of *evaluation* of the chained operator arguments' was *unspecified*. That means the execution could've first evaluated `addsomeStuff(cout, 3)` call (thus printing `3` first) and then proceed to print `a` and the returned value of `addsomeStuff(cout, 3)`.

With `C++17`, the order of *evaluation* is well defined - **left to right**. That means that if your compiler correctly implements the `C++17` standard, the only possible output is `132`.

If you are stuck with a pre `C++17` standard, you would need to first evaluate all the arguments and then use them in chained operator call **or** don't use chained operator calls:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    cout << a;
    cout << addsomeStuff(cout, 3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The former approach may alter the behaviour, but will be well-defined.

Comment: Thanks really helpfull, do you maybe have an link for the documenation?

Comment: @Daros it's pretty hard for me to gather every relevant part of the standard to provide such documentation, but if you want to read a little more about this, I highly suggest reading [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17).

Comment: @Daros [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/995714)