# C++: Problem with pointers in microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was using as my main IDE codeblocks, but I wanted to try visual studio. When I run the following code in Codeblocks (or an online C++ compiler) I get the right answer (output = 61), but when I put it in visual studio I get a weird answer (output= 90). Can somebody explain what is happening?

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int *s, int sz);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,10,20,30 };
    int siz = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int *ptr = arr;
    int output = sum(arr, siz);
    std::cout << "output = " << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int sum(int *int_input, int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return *int_input;
    }
    else
    {
        return *int_input + (sum(++int_input, --n));
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code using either codeblocks or visual studios debugger? What values are you getting vs what would you expect to get?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17 and decide whether you still need to ask the question.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: this clang warning should help you : `main.cpp:23:34: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'int_input' [-Wunsequenced]`

Answer (score 1):

Here you have unspecified behaviour in the next line

```cpp
*int_input + (sum(++int_input, --n))
```

You cannot say for sure is dereferencing `*int_input` is first or incrementing `++int_input`. To fix it, you need to rewrite code nextly:

```cpp
*int_input + (sum(int_input+1, --n))
```

Comment: Please be careful not to confuse new programmers by calling 'unspecified' behaviour 'undefined'

Comment: The operations with side effects, `--n` and `++int_input` are not on the same scalar object. The difference isn't pedantic, it is going to hit a C++ programmer every week of their carreer.