# Iterator increment leading to different results in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, iterator, clang

I encountered a weird issue in the following code snippet, leading to different results.

Apple clang (tested with 3.8.0 and 11.0) returns the expected value 10 but gcc (tested with 5.4.0 and 9) returns 12.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int acc(std::function<int(int, int)> func, std::vector<int> operands) {
    auto it = operands.begin();
    int result = func(*it, *(++it));  // <-- causing issue, ++it not working as expected
    if (operands.size() > 2) {
        for (++it; it!=operands.end(); ++it) {
            result = func(result, *it);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << acc([](int a, int b){ return a+b; }, {3, 5, 2}) << std::endl;
}
```

It can be reproduced for example, using [rextester.com](https://rextester.com/XYAZE98443).

While debugging I found out that the iterator increment `++it` seems to be the problem. Replacing it by `it+1` followed by a `it = it + 1` statement leads to the expected result in both compilers. But why is that handled differently among the compilers?

Comment: Related (if not a dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17

Comment: Note that the code has UB also when the size of the vector is less than 2. You may find useful one of the possible implementations of `std::accumulate`, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: @Bob__ `std::accumulate` takes an initial value, this uses the first element instead

Comment: Aside: you could use `std::plus<int>{}` instead of your lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why is that handled differently among the compilers?

Because before C++17, it was unspecified in what order function arguments are evaluated.

I would suggest not calling `func` in the initialisation of `result`.

```
int acc(std::function<int(int, int)> func, std::vector<int> operands) {
    if (operands.empty()) throw std::out_of_range();

    auto it = operands.begin();
    int result = *it;
    for (++it; it!=operands.end(); ++it) {
        result = func(result, *it);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that `std::function` is often overkill for passing functions. The standard library prefers templated higher-order functions, e.g. copying [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
template<class BinaryOperation >
int acc(BinaryOperation op, std::vector<int> operands)
```

Where `BinaryOperation` is any function-like type that is callable as `int(int, int)`, such as your lambda's type