# Is there an compiler bug in vc++? (I am a beginner)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, stream-operators

There are different effect between vc++(debug mode) and g++, with this code

test.hh

```
class Test
{
public:
    int a, b, c;
    Test(int a, int b, int c) : a{ a }, b{ b }, c{ c } {      }

    Test& operator++();
    Test  operator++(int);

};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t);
```

test.cc

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t)
{
    os << "{ " << t.a << ',' << t.b << ',' << t.c << " }";
    return os;
}

Test Test::operator++(int)
{
    Test temp{ *this };
    operator++();
    return temp;
}

Test& Test::operator++()
{
    ++a; ++b; ++c;
    return *this;
}
```

main.cc

```
Test t{ 1,2,3 };

std::cout << t << '\n'
          << t++ << '\n'
          << t;
```

in vc++ the result of execution is

```
{ 2,3,4 }
{ 1,2,3 }
{ 2,3,4 }
```

but in g++ it is

```
{ 1,2,3 }
{ 1,2,3 }
{ 2,3,4 }
```

so, Is there an compiler bug in vc++ or something what I has not learned.

Comment: To second @MikeCAT: IMHO, the impl. of your `operator++`s is OK. The unexpected results are caused by the `std::cout << t << '\n' << t++ << '\n' << t;`. Please, try again, splitting it in three separate statements: `std::cout << t << '\n'; std::cout << t++ << '\n'; std::cout << t << '\n';`.

Comment: It's never a compiler bug.

Comment: thanks, but I wanna know is this an undefined behavior?

Comment: Depends on the age of your compilers.     Before C++17,  the order of evaluations of `t`, `t++`, and (the second) `t` are unspecified in `std::cout << t << '\n' << t++ << '\n' << t;`.     Which, essentially, means the implementation must evaluate all three, but in any order it likes.   Since C++17,  the behaviour exhibited by your g++ is required.      If your vc++ version predates C++17 (or its documentation doesn't claim compliance with C++17 or later) then it is correct (or, more accurately, doing something permitted).   If it claims C++17/later compliance, then it is incorrect.

Comment: The answer is probably given in [Evaluation order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). (Sorry, for the unspecific answer. It's a bit  difficult topic.) I remember that some cases switched (with C++17) from Undefined to Implementation Defined. All I recorded: It's still nothing you really can rely on. ;-)

Comment: The only sensible way to deal with this mess is to avoid writing this kind of code.

Comment: I just tested your code, with C++17 enabled VC++ produces the same output as g++, with C++14 enabled it produces the output you described. So it seems VC++ is behaving correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `<<` has a psychological effect of pushing the idea of "sequencing".

While `std::cout << a() << b() << c()` conveys the idea of computing `a()`, then `b()` and then `c()` this is (was) false. You only know they will be put in the output stream in sequence, but they can be computed in any order ([before C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38501587/320726)).

This has been fixed recently (so may be the difference you are observing depends on which C++ standard you are using), but unfortunately only for common special cases like the left-shift operator that is overloaded for stream output (IMO another sad choice of C++ for a few reasons).