# Why variable, passed to a function by reference, doesn't immediately change its value?

Tags: c++, output

So here is the code (the program calculates the area of ring with specified outter and inner radiuses, nothing too special):

```
#include <iostream>

bool f(double ro, double ri, double &s) 
{
    const double eps = 1e-12;
    if (ro > ri + eps) 
    {
        const double pi = acos(-1);
        //s = pi * (ro * ro) - pi * (ri * ri);
        s = pi * (ro + ri) * (ro - ri);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    double s = 0;
    double ro, ri;  
    std::cin >> ro >> ri;
    std::cout << f(ro, ri, s) << ' ' << s << '\n'; 
    std::cout << s;
}
```

The question is, why, for example, for input
`5 4`
the output will be

```
1 0
28.2743
```

, not

```
1 28.2743
28.2743
```

?

Comment: Order of evaluation of arguments is not fixed in C++. Compiler is free to evaluate `s` first and call `f` later.

Comment: Before C++17 it's even worse as interleaving is allowed between computations of different arguments. Starting with C++17, there are some guarantees, though: e.g. in `a = b;` the left side will be evaluated after the right side.

Comment: Actually, there are guarantees regarding `<<` starting with C++17 as well. Try compiling your code with the C++17 standard. Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17).

Comment: @yeputons yep, with c++17 enabled, it works as expected, many thanks! x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Order of evaluation rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) have evolved, in particular, in C++17 for `E1 << E2`.

```
std::cout << f(ro, ri, s) << ' ' << s << '\n';
```

is guaranteed to be evaluated in expected order (left to right for `E1 << E2` ) in C++17 whereas it was unspecified before.