# Behavior of std::cout in C++?

Tags: c++, iostream, cout

I am observing a weird behavior with this little code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int get_input()
{
    int val;
    cin >> val;
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Res = " << get_input() << "\n";
    //printf("Res = %d\n", get_input());
}
```

I have compiled it in the simplest way by this command (I have also tried without the *-std* option):

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -o test.exe test.cpp
```

When I execute the code, I see

```
Res =
```

in place to have a blank line waiting for the user entry.
The behavior that I am expecting is that the "Res = " is displayed after the return of the *get_input* function. This is the behavior that I observed when I have used a C++ online compiler (like cpp.sh).

Could anyone explain to me what happens here ?

My gcc version on Debian 11 is :

```
g++ --version
g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Those operator << invokes aren't doing what you seem to think they are.

Comment: Also next time please don't describe the output you expect but rather _show_ it.

Comment: The linked question explains that the sequence is well-defined for C++17 and onwards. Not sure about pre-C++17, though. Clang-cl (on C++14) doesn't flag any unsequenced operations (which it normally does, when they exist).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things at play here: Operator precedence and Order of expression-evaluation. Operator precedence in case of << is left-to-right. The Order of evaluation was not defined in previous versions of the compiler; now it is.

As described in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501596/8316087), the Order of evaluation is now compatible with Operator precedence, which means it happens left-to-right:

1. `cout << "Res = "` happens first. The `<<` operator returns an instance of cout itself.
2. Then `cout << get_input()` happens, at which point in time `get_input` is called.
   ...and so on.

It used to differ based on the compiler, but now it's standardized.