# Why my code is print for 4 in the line head?

Tags: c++

It is my code in the following instruction:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class learning 
{
    public:
        static int func(int var) 
        {
            return var;
        }

        inline bool func(bool var=2 > 1) 
        {
            bool& va = var;
            int num = func(3);
            num += va;
            cout << num << " ";
            return num;
        }
};

int main() 
{
    learning len;
    cout << "Testing " << learning::func(6) << " " << len.func();

    return 0;
}
```

Why my cmd is print `4 Testing 6 1` but not is `Testing 6 1 4`?

Comment: Seems like *msvc bug*. The output is `Testing 6 1 4` in gcc and clang. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YzKha45Wv) . But msvc gives `4 Testing 6 1`.

Comment: @JasonLiam — not a bug. The 4 comes from inside `func`. The compiler is allowed to call that function before doing the stream insertions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that what you are seeing is that the order of operator-arguments-evaluation is implementation-specific (at least [prior to C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17)).  For further enlightenment, you might try running this program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int DebugFunc(int i)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "DebugFunc called with argument %i\n", i);
   return i;
}

int main()
{
    cout << DebugFunc(1) << DebugFunc(2) << DebugFunc(3);
    return 0;
}
```

On my compiler (clang++/MacOS), the program outputs this (Note that the "DebugFunc called" lines are fprint()'ed to `stderr` rather than using `cout`, to avoid complicating the output of the `cout` line in `main()`):

```
DebugFunc called with argument 1
DebugFunc called with argument 2
DebugFunc called with argument 3
123
```

... which is reasonable, but I think MSVC is free to evaluate the arguments in a different order, and output e.g. this:

```
DebugFunc called with argument 3
DebugFunc called with argument 2
DebugFunc called with argument 1
123
```

If MSVC is evaluating the arguments from right-to-left, that would explain why your program's "4" is printed before its "Testing".